# jmeter async response handle

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I want to test `http async` response between two servers.
Whole communication process between servers I described below:

1. Server 1 sends some data with method `PUT` to Serwer 2, and gets the normal sync response with `REQUEST ID` in the message response body.  `{"REQUESTID":"10"}`
2. After that, Server 2 starts sending asynchronous requests to Server 1 with method `POST` with various `RESPONSE ID`s in delay of 2 minutes until the `REQUEST ID = RESPONSE ID`.

Is there possiibility to test this scenario with 2 instances of *Jmeter* installed on those 2 servers?

My Solution for this is that after phase 1, I extracted `REQUEST ID` with regular expressions in *Jmeter* installed on Server 1.
And I also get simple JavaScript for compare `REQUEST ID` and `RESPONSE ID`.
But I don't know how to connect Request from *Jmeter* on Server 2 to become response for *Jmeter* on Server1.

Maybe it is possible in *Jmeter* to handle another request, or maybe another tool that can I use for this?

Comment: JMeter doesn't have anything nice for it, although if you google around you will find a few solutions. Personally, I tried a couple, but ended up using asymmetric tests in JMH framework (http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/448bd18c85f6/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_15_Asymmetric.java). It provides a nice structure to such tests and statistics gathering is clean and clear. But of course, it requires code development using something like Apache HTTP client or rest-assured (or similar) library for communications

Comment: Hmm... Thx for response. But his is too complicated for me right now. Maybe someone has less complicated solution for this problem?

Comment: well the best option you have with jmeter is following this tutorial: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AsyncDownloadTutorial/. Other option involves writing your own class in BeanShell (or other programmable) sampler. I couldn't achieve what I wanted with the first solution though, and second solution was too high maintenance (was easier to use another framework).